# When the manager is not responsible

Tags: manager, micro-management, corporate-responsibility

I have the honor of working with a manager who is not responsible for his actions and decisions. He usually blame others for his mistakes. You might guess that this person meddles in everything, not just with his opinions but you really should do his wrong and novice decisions.

Recently, he decided to start a new solution because of some problems with the last one. I tried to explain for him that all those problems are consequences of his opinions, he seemed to understand. But he keeps repeating that he has not been on the project and I'm the sole responsible for everything. Of course, not  this straight but in an indirect and friendly manner.

I have several problems with this situation:

1. I want everyone to know that it's not my fault.
2. I don't want him to be able to do this anymore. Since he has given me some responsibilities that I'm pretty sure is just for blaming purposes.

Unfortunately, I can't keep repeating myself, because I'll look insane and derange. For instance, when on a meeting and in the middle of his talk he points that I've been the project manager! I can't change the subject and argue that I wasn't!

The second problem is that his meetings with stakeholders are without me, and he can tell them whatever he wants. I almost never can have direct talk with them, and it's always through him. Even if I ask, I'll be usually redirected to him.

The third problem is somewhat personal, I'm getting cold about doing anything and accepting any responsibility… .

Any suggestion and tip is welcome!

Comment: Find a new job?

Comment: `I can't keep repeating myself, because I'll look insane and derange`  Not true.  You repeat it until people understand.  If people actually start complaining about you repeating yourself, then talk to these people individually and give them more personalized details.

Comment: @Kilisi, working on it.

Comment: So what's your question? "*I can't correct my boss, how do I correct him?*" is by definition unanswerable.

Comment: There's a lot of you said, I said, they said, we said type thing going on here. In the end, ultimately, you can't do much of anything other than quit. They'll be happy to see you go as your manager made you out to be a problematic employee.

Answer (score 3):

Document everything, if they ask you to do something, get it in e-mail. Keep a paper trail and make sure you have your obligations covered.

It's harder for someone to argue that it's your fault when you have an e-mail (Or similar) showing where the issue came from.

However, being a project manager, you should have the right to refuse something that this person suggests if you feel it is not appropriate. You might need to start pushing back against this manager, again using e-mail or some self documented service, saying that you do not agree with their suggestions or actions. It sounds like you are just allowing their options to roll over you and ignore what happens.

As for the stakeholders, again get it written in e-mail from the manager what they have requested and send it on to the stakeholders asking for confirmation. I wouldn't work on something coming from a second source, it allows too many mistakes and causes a scenario like Chinese Whispers.

In the end, document, document, and document some more. The larger the paper trail, the more chance you can push back and resolve these issues as they appear!

Comment: "send it on to the stakeholders asking for confirmation" that makes no sense. Considering he's just a regular employee, he has no business talking to them directly.

Comment: @Jonast92 *For instance, when on a meeting and in the middle of his talk he points that I've been the project manager* That quote states otherwise. If they are just a regular employee, then the manager shouldn't be referring to them as a project manager.

Comment: OP says that he clearly wasn't the project manager, sounds to me like he's just a regular employee being used as a punchbag for the manager's mistakes.

Comment: This is why documentation will be their best friend, the more they document, the more they will have as evidence. If they don't document, it becomes a he said, she said argument. The underlying point of the answer was to record everything, cover your back!

Comment: It really doesn't make a difference though. He's not going to send this to make a point to the shareholders, it's not in his line of duties. It's only going to make his boss more annoyed when he gets confronted with his lies, he should really just get out.

Comment: Or speak to a higher manager? Why allow other people to be submitted to such bad temperament. With evidence, then something could be done about this manager and prevent other people having to suffer the same issues